# Proof by Induction for $\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$

Tags: calculus, summation, induction, formal-proofs

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n- 1}{n}$$

How would you go about proving this by induction? the base case $n=1$ gives you $1/2 = 0$

The only thing I can think of using is $\sqrt{2}$, but that is not a natural number.

Comment: For $n=1$ you will have an empty sum which is equal to zero.  Ranging from the $1$'st position as the lower to the $0$'th position as the upper, there are no numbers in that range.

Comment: As for proof., can you express $\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$ as a sum or difference of smaller ordered fractions, like $\frac{1}{i}$ or similar?  Can you see how things cancel?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding of the base case is incorrect.  When $n = 1$, the sum on the left-hand side is empty, because the upper index is $n - 1 = 0$, meaning there are no terms to add.  This gives $0 = 0$ as desired.

The induction step is straightforward.  If we let $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)},$$ then $$S_{n+1} = S_n + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$  So if the induction hypothesis $$S_n = \frac{n - 1}{n}$$ is true, what does that say about $S_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

When $n = 1$, the sum on the left  side is empty, because the upper index is $n - 1 = 0$, that is  there are no terms to add.  This gives $0 = 0$ as desired.
Suppose that  $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)},$$ then we have to prove $$S_{n+1} =   \frac{n}{ (n+1)}.$$  So if the induction hypothesis $$S_n = \frac{n - 1}{n}$$ is true,  we have:
$$S_{n+1} = S_n+  \frac{1}{n (n+1)}.$$ that is $$S_{n+1} =\frac{n-1}{n}+  \frac{1}{n (n+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}.$$
The proof is compelete.

Answer (score 0):

The $2$ answers above are indeed excellent, and should be sufficient for your problem. Below I offer a different way of proving this result:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\\
&+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\\
&~~\vdots\\
&+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\end{align}$$
You should be able to see that all terms cancel out other than $1$ and $-\frac{1}{n}$
Hence,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n}$$
as required.